# Modify card style when closing a React Navigation stack card

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

My goal is to reproduce a stack card style that exists in the ios Spotify app in my react native application.

In Spotify, the currently playing song screen is a full screen modal:

[image]

When closing down the modal, the style of the card is modified to show a border top radius:
[image]

I am using React Navigation. For now I only achieved to style the card permanently with a border radius using the React Navigation 'options' prop to style the card. My goal is to show the border radius only while the stack card is getting closed down.

```
     <Stack.Screen
        name="ScreenName"
        component={ScreenComponentName}
        options={{
          cardStyle: {
            borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
            borderTopRightRadius: 20,
          },
        }}
      />
```

Any idea how I could modify the card style to add border radius only when the card is getting closed?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to provide a header in your Screen, rather than using the header provided by the Navigator. Then, you can set the borderRadius on your header View.

Your Navigator:

```
<Stack.Screen
  name="MyScreen"
  component={MyScreen}
  options={{
    headerShown: false,
  }}
/>
```

Your Screen:

```
function MyScreen() {
  const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();
  return (
    <>
      <View
        style={[
          styles.header,
          { borderTopLeftRadius: 38, borderTopRightRadius: 38 },
          { paddingTop: insets.top },
        ]}
      >
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Icon source={require('../assets/images/my-icon.png')}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Icon source={require('../assets/images/my-icon.png')}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.body}>
        <Text>Foo</Text>
      </View>
    </>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    paddingVertical: 20,
  },
  body: {
    flex: 1,
  }
});
```